# Big problem with booking system PHP + SQL

Tags: php, sql

I am creating now a new booking system, the part of the private rooms was done and I have now the part of the Dorm (sharing room).

The system works like that:

1. Insert coming day + leaving day + how many persons in the dorm
2. the system checks in the DB (of MYSQL by the way) if the is free room. 
   now how it checks? in the DB has coulmn of dates - one date is person. for example we have a dorm with those dates: 05/08, 05/08, 05/08, 05/08, 06/08, 06/08, 06/08, 06/08, 07/08, 07/08, 07/08, 07/08 - so there is 4 persons in dorm 05-07/08. for example if this room with 10 persons there is 4 of 10. now if you insert 7 people you dont have place. (it will be 11 of 10).
3. The system returns available rooms.

Now I want to do the next thing:
If there is 2 dorms. all of them place to 10 persons. all of them with 8 persons of 10. now coming 4 persons and want to register.. it wont give them because it checks dorm-dorm.. I want to do that the system will calculate the free places (there is 10-8 + 10-8 = 4 in 2 dorms). 
there is ideas?

My english its not very good I hope you will understand me,
THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

**EDIT:**

When I add dorm in the database:

```
ID | room_type|            persons                   | dates
------------------------------------------------------------------------
X  |  Dorm    |How many the dorm contain. not change.| of persons coming
```

if you have 5 dates same = there is 5 persons in the dorm in this date. for example.

Comment: Can you provide more details regarding the database structure? Abraço

Comment: Is the X | Dorm still in the same table as ID | roo_type, etc...? Nevermind, just saw the edit

Comment: X is number.. the ID of the dorm.. not change of course.. I dont understand what you asked...

Comment: So you need a query that returns a positive difference between persons - count(dates), right? That would return all the rooms with available spaces.

Comment: I dont think query will help, I need schema in PHP that take the all free places in all of dorms and checks if there is a place in number of dorms.. if there is 2 dorms with 8 of 10 and you want to insert more 4.. the system will 'say' that not available.. but there is places but in seperated dorms.

Comment: I might get kicked for this, but.. you could create a table with dorm/room id's, dates and number of people. Create triggers that update that table. No complex sql needed, the numbers are just there!

Comment: Luis, i disagree. A query could return all the rooms with available slots; from there, you can do whatever you want (eg: automatically or manually fill a room). A schema in PHP? What?

Comment: A schema in PHP I mean if you show me how can I do it with PHP.
However, how can I do it with SQL?

Comment: I'm trying to put the queries together; can you change the date format to YYYY/MM/DD ?

Comment: Not really. its MM/DD/YY.
What are you trying to do in the query?

Comment: to select all the rooms with available slots (persons - count(dates) where date > now()); something like this

Comment: Oh I understand. hmm.. I think I can do it in PHP. Its helping?

Comment: Yeah, PHP would certainly help.

Comment: Ok so I have those vars:
$request_persons (the request..)
$number_persons_contain (how many the dorm contain)
$number_persons_in_this_date (how many persons in those date)

Comment: Can i create temporary tables? Oh and give me the SQL code for the $number_persons_in this_date please

Comment: $number_persons_in_this_date = substr_count($room['dates'], $this->dateMonthYearArr[$index]);
this var is in for loop, the dateMonthYearArr is one date. $room['dates'] its all the dates in the DB of specific dorm.
And yes, you can create.


** I have to leave now. back in 30 min. Thank you very much any way on the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

OK so i'm typing this out of memory so it may need some fine-tuning but it should serve as a guide. Hope it helps.

1) First, let's create a temporary table that stores all of the ocuppied slots for any given room per date:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE room_availability
SELECT ID, DISTINCT dates, COUNT(dates) as full_slots FROM table 
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST(dates AS DATE)) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) > 0
GROUP BY dates ORDER BY ID;
```

2) Let's get all the available slots for any room:

```
SELECT table.*, table.persons - room_availability.full_slots as free_slots
FROM table INNER JOIN room_availability ON table.ID = room_availability.ID
where table.persons - room_availability.full_slots > 0
```

3) Finally, get rid of the temporary table and you're done

PS: the unix timestamp is there to help you list just the future dates.